# How to check Apple ID store balance without iTunes or iPhone?

Tags: accounts

How can someone check their balance without an iOS/OS X device and without installing iTunes?

For example if you lost or disposed of an old Apple device or simply left it at home... There must be a way to find out if you have any credit left

Answer (score 1):

You can call apple support provide your Apple ID and once the advisor verifies your identity  they can find out for you